# How do I get the latest note on the order at woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order, comments

I want when the order is placed in the (processing) position
Send SMS to the customer, how can I get the last note in the order and put it in the ( %comment% ) key?

```
    if ( isset( $this->options['wc_notify_customer_payment_successful_enable'] ) ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', array( &$this, 'successful_payment_notification_client' ) );
    }



* WooCommerce Successful payment notification client 
 *
 * @param $checkout
 */
public function successful_payment_notification_client ( $order_id ) {
    // Check the mobile field is empty
    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['mobile'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $order          = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $this->sms->to  = array( $_REQUEST['mobile'] );
    $template_vars  = array(
        '%order_id%'           => $order_id,
        '%order_number%'       => $order->get_order_number(),
        '%status%'             => $order->get_status(),
        '%billing_first_name%' => $_REQUEST['billing_first_name'],
        '%billing_last_name%'  => $_REQUEST['billing_last_name'],
        '%comment%'            => **What I say is here**
    );
    $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['wc_notify_customer_payment_successful_message'] );
    $this->sms->msg = $message;
    $this->sms->SendSMS();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order notes are saved as post comments, so you can use the WordPress function [`get_comments()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) to get the last note:

```
$args = array(
    'post_id' => $order_id,
    'orderby' => 'comment_ID',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'approve' => 'approve',
    'type'    => 'order_note',
    'number'  => 1
);

remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments', 'exclude_order_comments' ), 10, 1 );

$notes = get_comments( $args );

add_filter( 'comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments', 'exclude_order_comments' ), 10, 1 );
```

By default Woocommerce excludes order notes when calling the get_comments function. To prevent this, you have to remove the filter, call `get_comments()` and add the filter again. I copied this code from the function **`WC_Meta_Box_Order_Notes::output()`** in *wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-notes.php* and added "number", so you just get the last note.

Comment: thanks, Tell me how to use this code in the above code?

Comment: Put my code before `$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );` and then replace _What I say is here_ with `$notes[0]->comment_content`. For explanation: `get_comments()` returns an array of [WP_Comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment/) objects.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm so confused, can I ask you to get to know the exact code in the code?

Comment: I've put the full code at https://pastebin.com/nCKriwzF

Comment: Thanks, the code worked, is the use of the action ( woocommerce_order_status_processing ) to do this right?

Comment: Well I don't know all actions of WooCommerce so I think if it works it's the right place :D